# saving datatable into two databases

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have code to save the information in mydatatable into the database and also into my Audit file I am using the code below. however the first part of the code works great but the second part is not doing the job .Why is it that the same code is not working for the other database.it is not inserting the datatable into the Audit file

```
 '**************************************************************************************************************************************************
    '*********************  SAVE PRODUCT RAW MATERIAL DETAILS IN THE GRIDVIEW  ******************************************************

    Dim myConn As OleDbConnection = frmLogIn.Conn
    Dim oledbCmdBuilder As OleDbCommandBuilder
    Dim changes As DataTable

    Dim sql As String = "select * from ProductRawMaterial"
    Dim oledbAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, myConn)
    'Try
    oledbCmdBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(oledbAdapter)
    changes = myTable.GetChanges()
    oledbCmdBuilder.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges

    If changes IsNot Nothing Then
        oledbAdapter.Update(myTable)
    End If
    'myTable.AcceptChanges()
    myConn.Close()

    'Catch ex As Exception
    '    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    'End Try
    '***************************************************************************************************************************************************
    '*********************************************************    SAVING TO AUDIT   ****************************************************************

    Dim myKonn As OleDbConnection = frmLogIn.Connn
    Dim oledbCmdBuilderAudit As OleDbCommandBuilder
    'Dim changes As DataTable

    Dim sqlAudit As String = "select * from ProductRawMaterial"
    Dim oledbAdapterAudit As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlAudit, myKonn)
    'Try
    oledbCmdBuilderAudit = New OleDbCommandBuilder(oledbAdapterAudit)
    'changes = myTable.GetChanges()
    oledbCmdBuilderAudit.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges

    If changes IsNot Nothing Then
        oledbAdapterAudit.Update(myTable)
    End If
    myTable.AcceptChanges()
    myKonn.Close()

    'Catch ex As Exception
    '    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    'End Try
```

Comment: Same connection, same datatable, how do you expect the write to happen on a different datatable? (By the way, what do you mean for Audit file?)

Comment: Audit file is another database containimg tables that are similar to the database table for the app.

Comment: Then the second connection string is different. Right? Because we can't see the value of `frmLogIn.Conn`.

Comment: ~  Public Conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\WBS3000\WBS3000\Data\WBS3000A.ACCDB;persist security info = false")
    Public Connn As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\WBS3000\WBS3000\Data\WBS3000Audit.ACCDB;persist security info = false")
~

Comment: the connection strings are different, it is saving to different databases

Comment: I see you have removed the AcceptChanges(), are you sure that this call is never made between the first update and the second one?